# Dynamic Parameters Passing into the Report through Postgresql

Tags: ireport

I am working on Ireport 4.0.1 version.
My requirement is to pass parameter dynamically to the report that is my report consists two parameters like product_category and product_id. if i select value for product_category parameter and no value for product_id then the report should give data that filters on product_category else if i give both then filter upon both values. How can i acheive through Ireports.Please anyone could help me .

Thanks in Advance
Swathi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Passing Parameters to iReport 4.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467678/dynamically-passing-parameters-to-ireport-4-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional where clause condition, to make parameters optional try this :-

```
 WHERE  product_id= $P{product_id} or $P{product_id} is null
  AND   product_category= $P{product_category} or $P{product_category} is null
```

If the parameter is Collection type then you do not need this condition.

For more help you can refer this [Link](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2014/04/optional-where-clause-in-ireport.html)