# Dynamically Passing Parameters to iReport 4.0.1

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I'm working on iReport version 4.0.1. My query is

```
select productcategory as CATEGORYNAME,
    value as VALUE,m_product_id::text,
    product as NAME,count(pricexception) as stock 
from dtawm_stockcalculation_v
where m_product_id=$P{M_Product_ID} or $P{M_Product_ID} is null
    and productcategory=$P{M_Product_Category_ID} 
    or $P{M_Product_Category_ID} is null
group by value,m_product_id,product,productcategory
```

In which I am using two parameters: `$P{M_Product_ID}` and `$P{M_Product_Category_ID}`. Here I am setting default value for both parameters as `'%'` but I get an error:

```
Cannot cast char to string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we use " " to set the default value for string type parameter.